# Am I liable for damage or injuries caused by my dog?

Tags: legality

If I am in my woods with my dog, and it kills a protected species of songbird (which it knows it shouldn't), should I report this? If so, to whom? Should I expect a fine? This hasn't happened yet, but I like being ready, just in case.

Comment: I'm not sure who you would report to or if they would fine you. But yes, you are 100% liable for your dog and his or her actions.

Comment: I'd say you'd be liable to any protected animal, not just birds, as well as some non protected animals such as other peoples pets, farm animals - eg sheep worrying. In the UK for example a dead swan must be reported to the local RSPB/RSPCA, so if you have a local animal authority try them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have absolute responsibility for your dog, what it does is always your fault in the eyes of the law. If your dog kills an animal, you are also responsible for reporting it to the department that handles the preservation of wild animals(Naturvårdsverket here in Sweden). A fine might be imposed or if the case is severe, the dog might even be put down in some countries(though this is mostly the case if the attack is on a human).